# microservice : how to split my application

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, microservices

I thinking about to split my application into micro services but I' m not sure which part should have its own microservice or if I should regroup several parts into the same one.

My classes are :

File : a file in a tree. (differents subclasses like Folder, Card but it's not really important here)

Tag : a classification tag for a file

File note : comments on a file

User : an user of the app.

AccessRight : access rights of a file for differents users with differents rights like read, write, admin, superAdmin.

I'm pretty sure that the user logic should have it's own microservice, but should I regroup the other ones into a unique microService or split them ?

My old application use JavaEE and JPA, the entities was in the same package.
I'll use spring boot now and still JPA, but with microservices it seems more tricky to define the differents relations between the entities with the annotations provided with JPA, especially if the model is split into several microservices.

Here is the relations between my differents classes.

AccessRight : ManyToMany relationship between File and User with a right attribute. With JPA I need a special class with @IdClass to do that.

File and Tag : ManyToMany relationship.

FileNote : ManyToMany relationship between File and User with other attributes like a note( between[0-5]) and a comment.

User and File: simple oneToMany relation to define the owner of a file.

My application is avalaible here http://vps603552.ovh.net/ShareUrDoc/root.xhtml
it's still under construction but you can connect with login : test , password : pass.

It's a bookmark application only for tutorials urls, that allow users to make a research into the other people folders. The users can also make a link to any user's folder into their own tree, allow other users to manage the folder they choosed and so on.

[image: connexion]

Than you can activate the admin mode to manage the files.

[image: admin files]

Here is a github repository with the classes I described here, I only kept the essential.

https://github.com/kaizokun/kaizokun-shareUrDocModelDemo/tree/master/shareurdoc-model

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Splitting services right is one of the hardest questions out there, when it comes to Microservices. But from my perspective your application should not be split, because your models are too constrained to each other. My level of Information is: 2 separate Service means 2 separate databases. Because the services have to work independently... that would be my advice. But I am very interested what others are thinking!

Comment: But for an answer of high quality, I have to see the code. If you are able to share via github or other VCS, DM me on Twitter (twitter.blom.de)

Comment: Is it depends on multiple factors, first thing is your modules or services you are trying to make out of your application are tightly coupled, if yes then decoupled it using queues.

Is your application depends on local file system ? (Any I/O) if yes then it must use global storage to access all data by each microservice.

You must think of horizontal scalability while creating microservices. 
There are many more points you have to consider while creating microservice.

Comment: Also there are many cloud based solutions are there which will help you to manage your infra with application scalability like aws lamba which is serveless but you can use it as microsevice.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added the URL of my application if you want to test, and a github repository with the classes I described (I only kept the essential) so you can see the relationships between them. I'd say that some classes are too tied to be in several services so I would have put File, Tag, FileNote into the same microservice, I'm not sur for AccessRight , but User should be into a standalone service I think ( it is usually the case in the tutorials I read).